# erorr when installing mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pritunl

I'm trying to make a VPN tunnel with `pritunl` but after running the install script the DB is not starting up. is anyone able to help with this?

```
x mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sun 2023-06-04 06:55:15 UTC; 3s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 369 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=killed, signal=ILL)
   Main PID: 369 (code=killed, signal=ILL)
        CPU: 11ms

Jun 04 06:55:15 VPN systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jun 04 06:55:15 VPN systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=4/ILL
Jun 04 06:55:15 VPN systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'.

* pritunl.service - Pritunl Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pritunl.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-06-04 06:53:20 UTC; 1min 59s ago
   Main PID: 107 (pritunl)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 86859)
     Memory: 78.8M
        CPU: 1.852s
     CGroup: /system.slice/pritunl.service
             `-107 /usr/lib/pritunl/usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/pritunl/usr/bin/pritunl start

Jun 04 06:54:55 VPN pritunl[107]:     server_session = self._get_server_session()
```

Comment: Have a look at the mongod logfile